# this message appears when booting, is this an error? if so, how do I fix it?

Tags: boot

I've tried installing arch linux, but it failed because there was a problem with selecting the drive. Maybe it has something to do with this,

this message always appears when booting

> /dev/nvme/0n1p2: clean, 294960/7782400 files, 5698083/31127296 blocks

Comment: No, it is the output of the `fsck` command that was run at boot time. It is not an error, not even a warning. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Arch Linux is off-topic here. Feel free to ask your question at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) though, which is our sister site that supports all Linux distributions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not any error, it is just fsck command running on your disk. Just a regular process during booting up your computer.

You could be more specific about the issue.